# reading a MAC address in as a variable in BASH, should i use hex, do i need semicolons?

Tags: bash

i have a BASH script that does a few network utilities at home.  I want to read in a few variables at the start. For something fed into airodump-ng, which can take a MAC address as an arg just like: 00:01:02:03:04:05, how should input this for 'read'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read -p "Enter the MAC Address: " mac
echo "You entered the MAC Address: $mac"
```

Comment: @:siegex: so was it the 'trailing newline' that was giving me an error before? not having the -p

Comment: @bboy: without seeing your code I have no idea what was causing the error, let alone what your error was.